# Icone não aparece como desejado usando Fontawesome

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma table com botoes de acoes mas, como estao dentro da tag  o resultado é diferente do esperado.
OBS: preciso que direcione para uma nova rota, . Como arruma isso. Quero o resultado do lado direito.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">           
  <table class="table table-white">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/deletar/{{dataValues.id}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
        </a></td>
        
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mais esta indo, veja o exemplo com o link. Veja se sua variável esta imprimindo o link correto

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div class=container>
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491528/icone-n%c3%a3o-aparece-como-desejado-usando-fontawesome/491529?noredirect=1#comment914014_491529"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></a>
</di>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi sua dúvida, poder um pouco mais específico?

veja este exemplo do botão ficando a direita ou esquerda somente usando a classe float-right e float-left

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<div class=container>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</di>
<hr>
<div class=container>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-lrft"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</di>
```

Comment: Estou usando nodejs.  Quando clicar no botao quero ir para uma nova rota, mas, os botoes estao feios. Executa o codigo, pra voce ver a diferença nos botoes. O primeiro botao funciona mas esta feio, o segundo esta legal mas nao direciona para a rota que quero.

Comment: A sim, é porque em um esta usando uma tag a link e no outro somente button, você pode usar somente assim <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button> ou até mesmo no seu css ajustar a propriedade do a para ele ficar none a{text-decoration: none;}

Comment: Como ir pra essa rota " /deletar/{{dataValues.id}}" ao clicar no botao?